# css targeting div instead of form

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="formDiv">
    <form id="searchForm">
        <input type="text" name="weathersearch" placeholder="Search places">
    </form>
</div>
```

With the following css, it looks like this

```
.formDiv {
    background-color: red;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

[image]

I wish to have a larger *search box*, not a larger div. But targeting either the form id or the div gave me the same results, shown below. How would I make the form itself larger (i.e bigger horizontally and vertically).

```
#searchForm {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear. Title says "targeting div instead of element" but a div _is_ an element.

Comment: You want your input to be larger?

Comment: You need to affect the `input` not the `form`!!!

Comment: @APAD1, my bad, changed the title already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like to size the input element relative to `.searchForm` or `.formDiv`, do:

```
.searchForm input {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Otherwise, just set the height on the input element directly:

```
.searchForm input {
   height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.formDiv {
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
#searchForm {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
} 

#frmInput {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="formDiv">
  <form id="searchForm">
    <input type="text" id="frmInput" name="weathersearch" placeholder="Search places">
  </form>
</div>
```